# How can I make a react app run intendedly on the Html without installing node packages

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment-project

I have an assignment for the web development class to make a website(the front end part)
I asked my professor if I could use react and told me that I can as long the site can run intendedly on the Html

Is there any way to make a react app run intendedly on Html without the use of node packages?

Comment: `npm run build` - this usually generates static html and js